# Hide application in android device

Tags: android

I want to hide an application from user once it is installed. And I know
removing this line from manifest will work

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

but how can I use that application because I cann't see it in app list. Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: Have your cake and eat it, too?

Comment: why do you wnat to use the application icon, if it is not of any use.?

Comment: use transparent app icon for your app

Comment: but still it will display app name

Comment: check this application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.accusol.zipbooks in option menu it will set stelth mode that will set number when u dial that no it will start this appliction

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't add the launcher category, it could not be shown in launcher, and is just like a service which is hiden in your device. Then you have to use other app to start it. You should register intent-filter with other action and category in your app. The most common action should be ACTION_VIEW combine with category BROWSABLE, then you can use a url in brower or sms to open you app. The intent-filter should be like:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="openmyapp"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I want to open app by dialing a number...can you give me sample code ?

Comment: Sorry, Android do not provide such action. Dialing should only be got by broadcast, which means your app should be running all the time. You need a background service to listen to the broadcast.

Comment: Then please using url in browser.

Comment: The sample code has been provided.. just add it to your activity, and type `http://openmyapp` in your brower.